# How to change TextView gravity if different language ( English to Arabic)

Tags: android, translation

Android studio automatically switches sides when going from English to Arabic which is great. However, while using constraintlayout and gravity, the gravity stays the same, any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: show us the code you are using for gravity

Comment: what you want to achieve with this? Left Views on right & right views on left after language change?

Comment: I'm using xml but I think, in this case, I probably need to detect the language and change the gravity programmatically

Comment: we can't help without you showing the code of what you are actually doing

Comment: That's why you should avoid using `left` and `right` as gravity but rather use `start` and `end` and it'll switch those too then

Comment: I tried with `start` and `end` but didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats why you have to use RTL support. When you use `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your manifest you have to change in your XML. Whenever you set padding or margin on any side like left side, you will see a warning that will tell you add padding/margin on other side.

For gravity there is an option **viewStart**,**viewEnd** . Show when you use **viewStart** insteadOf **start** it will take care your layout gravity when laguage changed

Comment: You have to change gravity according to rtl support

Comment: `android:textDirection="locale"`
`android:textAlignment="viewStart"`
Instead of `android:gravity = "start"` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are refering to TextView's gravity (not layout gravity).

In xml, the attribute that supports both LTR and RTL layouts is *android:gravity="start""* and *android:gravity="end"*